# How to combine JSON object with same key and add their other corresponding values?

Tags: javascript, json

I tried the following code.

```
var SeatWithCat = [{
  "level": "Level II",
  "price": 5,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "B3"
}, {
  "level": "Level II",
  "price": 5,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "B1"
}, {
  "level": "Level I",
  "price": 10,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "A2"
}, {
  "level": "Level III",
  "price": 30,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "C1"
}, {
  "level": "Level III",
  "price": 30,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "C2"
}, {
  "level": "Level V",
  "price": 50,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "E1"
}, {
  "level": "Level II",
  "price": 5,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "B2"
}, {
  "level": "Level VI",
  "price": 2,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "F1"
}];
var temp = [];
var jsonarr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < SeatWithCat.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j < SeatWithCat.length; j++) {
    if (SeatWithCat[i].level === SeatWithCat[j].level) {
      temp.push({
        level: SeatWithCat[i].level,
        quantity: SeatWithCat[i].quantity + SeatWithCat[j].quantity,
        price: SeatWithCat[i].price + SeatWithCat[j].price,
        seats: SeatWithCat[i].seats + "," + SeatWithCat[j].seats
      });
      SeatWithCat = SeatWithCat.filter(function(el) {
        return el.level !== SeatWithCat[i].level;
      });
      jsonarr = SeatWithCat;
      alert(JSON.stringify(temp));
    }
  }
}
var finalObj = temp.concat(jsonarr);
alert(JSON.stringify(finalObj));
```

Output:

```
[{
  "level": "Level II",
  "quantity": 2,
  "price": 10,
  "seats": "B3,B1"
}, {
  "level": "Level III",
  "quantity": 2,
  "price": 60,
  "seats": "C1,C1"
}, {
  "level": "Level VI",
  "quantity": 2,
  "price": 4,
  "seats": "F1,F1"
}, {
  "level": "Level I",
  "price": 10,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "A2"
}, {
  "level": "Level V",
  "price": 50,
  "quantity": 1,
  "seats": "E1"
}]
```

It's Working fine for two objects having same level but if there are greater than two objects in the array with same level its not working. My requirement is to add values for any number of objects having same level.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge JSON Object with same "key" and add their "value" using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833165/merge-json-object-with-same-key-and-add-their-value-using-javascript)

Comment: For what it's worth, you have an array of objects; not a "JSON object". JSON is a textual format that can be parsed *into* objects. As soon as you're actually using it as data, it's no longer JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to collect unique items in an dictionary, and then transform the dictionary back to array using `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
function combine(arr) {
  var combined = arr.reduce(function(result, item) {
    var current = result[item.level];

    result[item.level] = !current ? item : {
      level: item.level,
      price: current.price + item.price,
      quantity: current.quantity + item.quantity,
      seats: current.seats + ',' + item.seats
    };

    return result;
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(combined).map(function(key) {
    return combined[key];
  });
}

var SeatWithCat = [{"level":"Level II","price":5,"quantity":1,"seats":"B3"},{"level":"Level II","price":5,"quantity":1,"seats":"B1"},{"level":"Level I","price":10,"quantity":1,"seats":"A2"},{"level":"Level III","price":30,"quantity":1,"seats":"C1"},{"level":"Level III","price":30,"quantity":1,"seats":"C2"},{"level":"Level V","price":50,"quantity":1,"seats":"E1"},{"level":"Level II","price":5,"quantity":1,"seats":"B2"},{"level":"Level VI","price":2,"quantity":1,"seats":"F1"}];

var result = combine(SeatWithCat);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table as reference to the same level object in the result set.

Iterate the array and check for hash - if not set generate a new object with the actual properties. Otherwise add `quantity` and append `seats`.

This proposal uses only one loop.

```js
var seatWithCat = [{ level: "Level II", price: 5, quantity: 1, seats: "B3" }, { level: "Level II", price: 5, quantity: 1, seats: "B1" }, { level: "Level I", price: 10, quantity: 1, seats: "A2" }, { level: "Level III", price: 30, quantity: 1, seats: "C1" }, { level: "Level III", price: 30, quantity: 1, seats: "C2" }, { level: "Level V", price: 50, quantity: 1, seats: "E1" }, { level: "Level II", price: 5, quantity: 1, seats: "B2" }, { level: "Level VI", price: 2, quantity: 1, seats: "F1" }],
    result = [];

seatWithCat.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!this[o.level]) {
        this[o.level] = { level: o.level, price: o.price, quantity: o.quantity, seats: o.seats };
        result.push(this[o.level]);
        return;
    }
    this[o.level].quantity += o.quantity;
    this[o.level].seats += ',' + o.seats;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```